# Splitting an input file in Java

Tags: java, split

I've spent a good couple hours trying to solve this myself, but I just can't figure it out and decided to ask.

I am loading a file into my program for me to split into three fields.Each line in the text file contains 3 comma separated values 
`double, double, char`. I plan on creating an array for each and then type wrapping each string in each array index into its respective array of its type. So first I need to split each line of the input.

So I opened the file and split the input as such:

```
Scanner fileIn = null;
String temp = "";
String[] data;
String fileName = "test.txt";
File textFile = new File(fileName);
fileIn = new Scanner(textFile);

while(fileIn.hasNext()){
temp += in.next;
}

data = temp.split(",");

for(String string: data) {
System.out.println(string);
}
```

*NOTE: I know this isn't the prettiest way, but this is just one of the many ways I tried to produce my output.

After using various variations of `.split()` such as `temp.split(",")` `temp.split(",|\n")` `temp.split(",|\r")` `temp.split(",|\r\n")` and others I get the same output of

```
0
0
.1
0
.2
0
.3
0
.4
0
.5
0
```

So basically after the last character of a line gets paired with the first character of the next line. And I have no Idea how to get it to output to one character per line. [Here's](http://txt.do/6q2o) a copy of the text file. Thanks for all the help in advance!

EDIT: Text [copy](http://txt.do/6q2g) of output.

Comment: What is `in.next`?  I'm guessing that that's not the code you actually wrote.    In any case, please add `System.out.println(temp);` before you try to do the `split`, and make sure that `temp` is what you think it is.  The way you're creating `temp` is strange-looking enough to make me suspicious.  In other words, I think the problem may not be with the `split`, it may be with what comes before the `split`.

Comment: You need two loops: first to read each line in a file, and second to read each number in a line. For first use nextLine, for second use next.

Comment: Why are you using scanner on a text file? Java has readers for text files. Try a BufferedReader... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: @ajb for temp I get a very long string. It was just one of my many attempts to split the string. probably not the best idea.

Comment: @Sigismundus I'm going to try that.

Comment: @Invexity this is part of a method for an assignment, and my professor taught us file input by scanner. I'll check BufferedReader out though.

Comment: Impress your professor, think outside the box.

Comment: @Invexity yeah, thanks for your suggestion. Definitely seems more suitable for what I need it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your while loop. Just after the loop, temp looks like...

```
0,0,.1,0,.2,0,.3,0,.4,0,.5,0,.6,0,.7,0,.8,0,.9,0,.10,0,.
```

You can manually insert a comma like...

```
while(fileIn.hasNext()){
        temp += fileIn.next() + ",";
}
```

Then temp looks like...

```
0,0,.,1,0,.,2,0,.,3,0,.,4,0,.,5,0,.,6,0,.,7,0,.,8,0,.,9,0,.,10,0,.,
```

which can be split with ","

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks. I can't believe I missed that in the temp that there's no "," between them. Thanks again.

Comment: LOL! No problem! It's always helpful to have a second set of eyes. :-)